# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip'

Tags: android, github, gradle, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVkN.png)I have cloned an app from GitHub, but am finding issues like could not install Gradle distribution from a specified
URL, I also tried downloading several other projects but getting the same error.
can I please get a help to resolve this issue?[Gradle error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8iAC.png)

Comment: Did you try to open https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip this link in your browser to test , its downloading or not ? If not then its a connection issue. Otherwise you should provide more info in your post such as you build script/gradle plugin version,project structure etc.

Comment: I tried downloading it, it was, and have no idea where to paste them, what should be done next?

Comment: Did you try to run Android Studio as Administrator ? try.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that @ZahidIslam

Answer (score 0):

Manually solution -

1. Download Gradle From this [link](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip) and extract.
2. From android studio **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle** select Use Gradle from : Specified Location , then specify the directory of extracted gradle folder by browsing it and apply.
   [image]

To get latest Gradle check [this](https://gradle.org/releases/) link.
Which *Gradle Plugin version* requires which Gradle version to check that visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) .  `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"` in this case you are using plugin version 4.2.1 which requires minimum 6.7.1 gradle version .

To use Gradle version 6.1.1 you have to use plugin version 4.0.0+. You can use `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"`for gradle 6.1.1.

Its better to use latest gradle . Hope this will help you . Thanks.
`

Answer (score 0):

I tried many other things, but nothing worked.
I got the solution but,
git checkout -b josus origin/release-4.0
git checkout -b {your_github_name} origin/{your_branch_name}

Answer (score 0):

I ran Android Studio as administrator and fixed it.