# Gradle sync failed after deleting some files in gradle wrapper and cache. what should I do?

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

in `Users/myName/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

I deleted some files in this directory. the files are like this

```
gradle-5.x.x-all
```

because I thought I no longer need it and I just need the latest version. (i.e `gradle-7.0.2-all` )

and in `Users/myName/.gradle/caches`

in this directory, I also delete some files, and I delete 'old' file, only left 7.0.2

and when I open my android project, the gradle failed to sync, and I have this error

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0."

how to solve this issue? can I get that deleted file back? unfortunately I have deleted it from trash

I may delete more files, but unfortunately I forget. please help :(

I have tried to:

1. invalidate cache and restart
2. delete .gradle folder in my home directory

but I have this error now

> Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown

When I try to rebuild the project. I have this error

> Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:].
> Build mode: REBUILD.
> Tests: None.

Comment: are you using gradle from `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle|Use Gradle from` gradle-wrapper.properties file ? then what gradle version defined by  `distributionUrl` in gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: @ZahidIslam thanks for the response. I have this distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

Comment: change to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
` and try to sync

Comment: @ZahidIslam I don't know why but I get Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown

Comment: would you please check gradle plugin version used in top/project level build.gradle? such `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'`

Comment: if not fixed you may try manual path , instead `gradle-wrapper.properties` .  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367745/4327305

Comment: @ZahidIslam yup thats the problem. after I change it the gradle can sync. if you want, you can post it as an answer. Thx

Comment: It's okay no problem .